# Google Analytics crash with Swift 2.0

Tags: ios, swift, google-analytics, fatal-error

I've just installed `GoogleAnalytics` from `CocoaPods` and tried to use it, suddenly it crashes with an error:

```
fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
```

The crash occurs in this part:

```
override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)

    let tracker = GAI.sharedInstance().defaultTracker
    tracker.set(kGAIScreenName, value: "Main")

    let builder = GAIDictionaryBuilder.createScreenView()
    tracker.send(builder.build() as [NSObject : AnyObject])
}
```

And when reaching this line:

```
tracker.set(kGAIScreenName, value: "Main")
```

Maybe it has something to do with the framework is bridged from Objective-C?

---

**Update**

So I fixed the crash by wrapping it with an if statment and still nothing sent to Google Analytics:

```
let name = "Main"
if let gai = GAI.sharedInstance() {
    if let tracker: GAITracker = gai.trackerWithTrackingId("TRACKING_ID") {
        tracker.set(kGAIScreenName, value: name)

        let builder = GAIDictionaryBuilder.createScreenView()
        tracker.send(builder.build() as [NSObject : AnyObject])

        print("tracker initialized")
    }
}
```

Comment: Does `tracker initialized` get printed, or is the inner `if let` failing? If so, are you absolutely sure that the tracking id value you're using is valid - the docs say it will return nil if it's invalid.

Comment: `tracker initialized` get printed. yes. but the analytics doesn't show nothing.

Comment: Have you tried proxying the app and seeing if it's sending web requests to GA?

Comment: I use http://www.charlesproxy.com/

Comment: Ok, let me check it out.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/91909/discussion-between-yossi-tsafar-and-rich-tolley).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I figured out the problem, I used `Google Analytics` with `CocoaPods` as explained in the [Google Analytics iOS tutorial](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/ios/v3/?ver=swift) and added this line to the Bridging Header file:

```
#import <Google/Analytics.h>
```

but I guess that's not enough, after adding these lines:

```
#import <GoogleAnalytics/GAI.h>
#import <GoogleAnalytics/GAIDictionaryBuilder.h>
#import <GoogleAnalytics/GAILogger.h>
#import <GoogleAnalytics/GAITrackedViewController.h>
#import <GoogleAnalytics/GAITracker.h>
```

It worked perfect. (Thanks Rich Tolley for the help)

Comment: I have exactly the same problem as you but this solution does not work for me.

Comment: @cnbuff410 Did you found another solution ? Cause this solution didn't work for me either.

Answer (score 1):

The [docs](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/ios/v3/reference/interface_g_a_i#a72941e445c4e4ec9b8c13b7f1cf73977) for the `GAI` class have this to say about `defaultTracker`

> >
>   For convenience, this class exposes a default tracker instance.
>   This is initialized to nil and will be set to the first tracker that is instantiated in trackerWithTrackingId:. It may be overridden as desired.

So I'm guessing you need to call `trackerWithTrackingId:` somewhere, or if you are already doing it, make sure it happens before this method is called.

Comment: I'm not calling exactly this method, but in the new analytics you don't have to.

Comment: But `defaultTracker` is still nil, so maybe there's some other setup step missing. BTW where did you find out that you didn't need to call it anymore? The docs link in my answer is for the v3 docs, and the main page says it was updated on the 2nd of September. (Although based on previous experience I would hardly be surprised if the GA docs turned to be incomplete/inconsistent)

Comment: I didn't called it because there is another way to initialize the tracker in the latest SDK. Check this out: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/ios/v3/?ver=swift

Answer (score 0):

For me I had to add those lines in the AppDelegate:

```
var configureError:NSError?
GGLContext.sharedInstance().configureWithError(&configureError)
assert(configureError == nil, "Error configuring Google services: \(configureError)")
```